# Django Class-based view pass custom request

Tags: django, testing, python-unittest, django-class-based-views

I am using `unittest` in my project, and the following is my test code.

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from lists.views import NewListView

@patch('lists.views.NewListForm')
class NewListViewUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.request = HttpRequest()
        self.request.POST['text'] = 'new list item'
        self.request.user = Mock()
    def test_passes_POST_data_to_NewListForm(self, mockNewListForm):
        NewListView(self.request) # The important bit
        mockNewListForm.assert_called_once_with(data=self.request.POST)
```

I want to pass a custom request, which as you see has some POST data. I had originally had a view, so I could pass a custom request. Now, with a class based view, how can I do that? I am currently getting an error which says:

```py
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I did try `NewListView.as_view(self.request)`, but that says

```py
TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I know you should use the Django test client and make POST requests using the URL, not calling the actual view, but this is how they did it in the book I am currently studying (*Test-Driven Development with Python* by Harry Percival. Unfortunately, he doesn't seem to have updated his appendices, where he teaches the class based view stuff, so I am doing it my self. Or trying to.)

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you make a dummy request using Django's test client?

Comment: The book did it this way. And there are a lot of this instances, I just showed one, which makes it hard to edit. I want to know if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is possible somehow, but, this is not the *right* way to test

Comment: True. But like I said, the book did it this way, and there are too many instances to easily edit.

Comment: I've figured out why the book does it like this, he doesn't use the Django test client in this test as he thinks it becomes too 'integrated'.

Comment: What that means is that using the test client is an integration test as it touches on multiple objects and this is a unit test. It's a bit silly, cause in the real world, no one makes unit tests like this as the path from url to view, request creation, post handling is all tested well by Django itself. So for all intents and purposes, they can be considered a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. `as_view()` creates the functional view version of the CBV that can be handed a request:

```py
@patch('lists.views.NewListForm')
class NewListViewUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # ...
    def test_passes_POST_data_to_NewListForm(self, mockNewListForm):
        NewListView.as_view()(self.request)
        mockNewListForm.assert_called_once_with(data=self.request.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'` in a `dispatch` method according to the traceback. Could you tell me what that means and how to solve it? Maybe I should set `request.method = ''` in the `setUp`?

Comment: You should set request.method to 'POST' and provide request.path too, I'm guessing. You could use `django.test.client.RequestFactory`, but then you may be doing to much "integrated stuffs". :)